# Automating input of SQL queries in textbox in a website using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to automate a manual process using Python Selenium, where I have write a block of SQL codes within a textbox  in a website on a daily basis.

We can input Texts using send_keys(). But I'm not sure How can we input a Block of SQL queries with a textbox using python selenium so that I can automate this process.

Basically We Input SQL queries in the textbox in our website on a daily basis and whatever queries are there within the textbox the website executes them and provides the result in dashboard. Basically the textbox acts as a Compiler for SQL queries.

Can anyone help me how to input a Block of SQL queries to a textbox in a website using python selenium as to automate this daily process.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath().send_keys("select * from table");

Comment: What are your code trials? , Welcome to SO!! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly and follow the same in future post. Don't put the screenshot of code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding on your query, you are trying to enter a bunch of SQL commands line by line in the same text box, the `send_keys` is a good option but to enter the text without leaving the text box, you have to use `Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER)`.

For example:

```
driver.find_element("locator","value").send_keys("select * from table, Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER), .....")
```

Otherwise if different text boxes are to be used to enter different SQL commands, then `send_keys("")` is fine to work.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,
But however please check this question which im struggling to find a solution for this.

[Python Multiline String changes the indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63889266/8046410)