# Python Multiline String changes the indentation

Tags: java, sql, python-3.x, selenium, browser-automation

I'm working on a Automation with Python and Selenium.
I have to paste a block of SQL & Java Script codes within the Text Area in the website.
I used many ways to send the strings, but it changes the indentation.
Is there a way to send the codes/strings without any changes to the indentation ?
I used all the below and nothing worked,

```
textwrap.dedent(prdrsql1)
textwrap.dedent(prdrsql1).lstrip()
(prdrsql1).lstrip()
(prdrsql1).strip()
```

Code:

```
prdrsql1 = ("""
        SELECT DISTINCT CAST(q2.SubjectId AS varchar(32)) as SubjectId, q2.SubjectNum, 
'A' as ItemOid,
q1.B as VisitId,
q1.[C] as VisitRepeatKey,
q1.[D] AS FormOid,
q1.E as FormRepeatKey,
'Y' as Data
FROM Table.A.ABC q2 with (NOLOCK)
    Right Join (
    select hashkey, SubjectNum, 
    (CASE WHEN C is null THEN 'SUBJECT' ELSE [D] END) AS 
    [D], 
    (CASE WHEN G is null THEN 'SUBJECT' ELSE [G] END) AS 
    [G], 
    FormOID, [DD], AB,ABC
    from Table.A.ABC with (NOLOCK) where abc=123
    ) q1
    on q1.abc = q2.qbc
    AND q1.AA = 1 and AAA=1""")
```

Output:

[The is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh8Ox.png)

Because of this the compiler is not compiling the code  and giving an Error.

I need to send these SQL & Java Script (*I've another text field where I've to send JS codes which has For Loops and IF conditions*) Codes without altering the Indentation or at least starting all the lines from the starting of the line.
Can someone please provide your inputs?

[The Compiler compiles the codes only if the code is as below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJfZy.png)

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is very simple. You just copy pasted the SQL Query hoping that it'll work here as it is. The thing here in Python is that it is indent sensitive. a wrong indent would cause a unintended trouble. Now, on the other hand SQL Queries and JavaScript Code, both of there are not indent sensitive. These depend on ; (semicolon) to break the line. This means that even if you specify 300 commands in one line separating each one with a ; (semicolon) the commands will execute without hassles. But the same won't work here in case of python.

If you try the below code, this will work for you and you'll get the expected results.

```
prdrsql1 = ("SELECT DISTINCT CAST(q2.SubjectId AS varchar(32)) as SubjectId, q2.SubjectNum, 'A' as ItemOid, q1.B as VisitId, q1.[C] as VisitRepeatKey, q1.[D] AS FormOid, q1.E as FormRepeatKey, 'Y' as Data FROM Table.A.ABC q2 wit (NOLOCK) Right Join ( select hashkey, SubjectNum, (CASE WHEN C is null THEN 'SUBJECT' ELSE [D] END) AS [D], (CASE WHEN G is null THEN 'SUBJECT' ELSE [G] END) AS [G], FormOID, [DD], AB,ABCfrom Table.A.ABC with (NOLOCK) where abc=123) q1 on q1.abc = q2.qbc AND q1.AA = 1 and AAA=1")
```

Try printing and verifying the output of this variable in your SQL Client before actually using it.